# Map a virtual address to a specific physical address

Tags: c, virtual-memory, segmentation-fault

I need to handle some page faults in user mode. I use for that the [GNU libsigsev](http://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/) library on an x86_64 Ubuntu-12.04 64 bits.

As a first step, I want to map the virtual address of an unmapped variable to the same physical address of an other allocated variable. As I have moved all the process' contents above 1GB in the
address space, I am sure that the unmapped variable address is not in use.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sigsegv.h>

int handler (void *fault_address, int serious)
{
    printf("Page fault\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    sigsegv_install_handler (&handler);
    int* p = (void*)0x55555; // This virtual address is not used by the process
    int *q = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 0x77; // This should have the same effect as *q=0x77
    return 0;
}
```

Is that possible ? For now the program outputs:

```
Page fault
Page fault
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: have you tried **anything**?

Comment: I don't really know what to try, mmap seems not to fit.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Especially the part where you put `0x55555` to `p` (You can't assign a random virtual address that probably has no virtual page entry). What you might want is shared memory (`man shm_open`), but it seems pointless for a single process !? Or are you simply looking for `p = q` ?

Comment: I would like à page table entry for the virtual address of p that points to the same physical address as q. When you dereference p, you ends up with same physical address as q.

Comment: @NoWiS You were right! What I needed was shm_open to create a shared file from which ```q``` would be directly mapped. Then on ```*p = 77```, it will page fault and I will mmap p to the same place as q (but p has a different virtual address).

Comment: anotherCode245, are you sure that you need physical addresses? Are you working with external hardware and its DMA? Usually physical addresses are used only in kernel-mode device drivers, and you can't have physical addresses in user-mode without special help from kernel.